# Python: use regex to extract strings from text and put them into a list

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file and its content has the following pattern, `some strings ( a ; b ; c ) some strings ( d ; e ; f ) and so on`

How can I extract them from the text and put them into a list like `lists = [['a', 'c', 'b'], ['d', 'f', 'e']]`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because my regex-fu not as strong as some's but I'd do it in 2 stages and only use regex on the first.

```
import re

text_ = "some strings ( a ; b ; c ) some strings ( d ; e ; f ) and so on"

#extract anything bounded by parenthesis
pat1 =re.compile(r"(\([^\)]+\))")
split1 = pat1.findall(text_)

def split(substr):
    """ dont need to be all fancy, split on ; after stripping the parenthesis """
    return [v.strip() for v in substr.lstrip("(").rstrip(")").split(";")]

result = [split(val) for val in split1]

print(result)
```

#### output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Alternatively, you can let the first regex exclude the parenthesis in the groups so that it simplifies your split function.  Cleaner, same output.

```
pat1 =re.compile(r"\(([^\)]+)\)")
split1 = pat1.findall(text_)

def split(substr):
    """ dont need to be all fancy, split on ; after stripping the parenthesis """
    return [v.strip() for v in substr.split(";")]
```

Comment: you can also use `.strip('() ')` instead of `rstrip` and `lstrip`.

Comment: @VishalSingh  Not really.  Try running this `print("not really", ")(".strip('() '), "beware strip multichar behavior")`.  You want a lstrip and a rstrip that only operate on particular chars, not in combination.

Answer (score 0):

For a single list:

```
>>> text = "some strings ( a ; b ; c ) some strings ( d ; e ; f ) and so on"
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"([a-z])(?= ;| \))")
>>> regex.findall(text)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

For two lists:

```
>>> regex2 = re.compile(r"(?<=\( )([^\)]+)(?= \))")
>>> [match.split(' ; ') for match in regex2.findall(text)]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```